# Simple drupal module for in-software login

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to make a simple drupal module that does the following:
-Responds to a simple http request containing a username and password by checking if that user
is part of a role/has a permission, and responds with a session key
-Can check a session key and username for correctness

I need it for a game that I'm making that will require sign-in to use multiplayer,
the game will get the session key from the server, and send that to a server with the username, and the server will verify that they bought the game before letting them connect, kinda like Minecraft's authentication.
Can anyone help me find resources on program this into a drupal module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use Drupal as your login provider, don't worry, you don't need to make a custom module. You can just use the Drupal [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module. You can use it to send HTTP request with post data of your user credentials.

Comment: Thanks! This is even closer to what I was looking for than I expected to find!